# Will the Lightning calendar app be available in 11.10?

Tags: evolution, thunderbird, 11.10, calendar, google-calendar

Further, if it is available, will it be integrated into the indicators by default?

I need my google calendar offline, so is it back to evolution?

Comment: Do you actually want to know what the default app will be, or do you just want to know if lightning will be available? Or do you want examples of offline calendar apps? Between your title and body it appears there are three different questions here.

Comment: I wanted to know if lightning was going to be available (that was my priority because it wasn't available yet in tb7).As a curiosity I would like to know if it was going to be integrated in datetime indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Calendar Extension for Thunderbird**

Install this plug-in: [xul-ext-lightning](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xul-ext-lightning) [image: Install xul-ext-lightning]

---

**Google calendar and Evolution....**

Currently there is a bug in evolution. A workaround to do the following :

- [Option to sync to Google Calendar doesn't show up in Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73828/option-to-sync-to-google-calendar-doesnt-show-up-in-evolution/73856#73856)

---

**How to migrate from evolution to thunderbird...**

- [Migrating from Evolution to Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird/27413#27413)

Answer (score 2):

Lightning is available in Ubuntu 11.10 though to my knowledge it is not installed by default.

Comment: was update today! :)

Answer (score 1):

Google calendar will be available as an offline html5 app by the end of this week.

- [Google offline chromium apps](http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/31/googles-new-html5-chrome-apps-for-gmail-calendar-and-docs-give-users-offline-access/)

It will be available for chrome/ium only initially but it wont be long before it will be available through Firefox or Opera

Comment: The title of the Question has been changed many times Jo. His question was does he have to go back to Evolution to be able to access his google calendar offline I was providing an alternative which would work should there be any problems with lightning in Thunderbird. IMO relying on one app is dangerous when it is important data you need to access having an alternative is never bad.