# Option to sync to Google Calendar doesn't show up in Evolution

Tags: 11.10, evolution, calendar, google

I did a clean installation of Oneiric and since Evolution is not included by default, I added it by doing apt-get install evolution. However, when I try to create a new calendar and sync it with Google I only get three options: "On This Computer", "On the Web" and "Weather". There used to be an option to include google calendars but it is not there now. It appears, though, in another computer that I upgraded from Natty so I assume that the option still exists. What package am I missing?

Comment: @jorge castro isn't dupe, because the option to add google calendar is not available as you can see in picture number 1 and you have to activated.... for some reason this is not automatic....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/886386) but can be resolved following this steps:

**YOU HAVE THIS AND GOOGLE CALENDAR ISN'T AVAILABLE**

[image]

- Close Evolution :
- Install Gnome Config Editor

> sudo apt-get install gconf-editor

- navigate evolution -> address book :

[image]

- Double Click on the right side and find the Google part select edit an copy all the line (all strange character are important):

[image]

- then navigate evolution -> calendar :

[image]

- double click on the right side -> Add and paste the line you copy before ...

now you can see :

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That solved my problem. I assume this is a bug. Thanks a lot!