# How can I migrate my data from Evolution to Thunderbird?

Tags: evolution, thunderbird, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating from Evolution to Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird)

Since it will be the new standard email-client in the upcoming distribution, I thought about taking a look at Thunderbird.

Now my first issue is: How can I migrate all my data (contacts, email, account settings) from Evolution to Thunderbird with as little trouble as possible?

I did already search the internet, but all I could find was outdated information...

gr33tz panmari