# Manually migrate from evolution to thunderbird

Tags: evolution, thunderbird, migration

After installing 11.10, evolution stayed the default mail client on my system. I guess that is because I (a) already had thunderbird installed for a test-drive a while ago and/or (b) I had evolution configured quite extensively.

I prefer to remain with Ubuntu's choice and would like to setup thunderbird as my default client.

Can I:

- Set Thunderbird as default client trough  a script or command? Or do I need to edit some config files?
- Migrate my mailaccounts and their settings (login, smtp etc)? Is it possible to manuall run the migration path that other upgrading users would get?
- Migrate my calendar settings to lightning?
- Migrate my mailfilters?
- Migrate my addressbook?

Comment: possible duplicate -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird/27413#27413

Comment: Probably not. Other question is about migrating from the *default* evolution to the none-default *thunderbird*. Things have very much changed now that thunderbird became the default mailclient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is this migration walk-through:
http://nucleussystems.com/blog/migrate-evolution-to-thunderbird

In regards to changing the default mail client, that is possible via "System Info" in oneiric(11.10). There is a section called "Default Applications" in which you can set the default mail client.