# What is the best way to integrate my Google calendar with Ubuntu?

Tags: google-calendar

I know that you can integrate Google calendar with evolution, but it doesn't seems to work for me. Once I add something to my Google calendar, it never updates in Evolution.

Please don't send me to [the Ubuntu help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleCalendarWithEvolution) because I already tried following the instructions there a lot of times and nothing works.

Comment: Works fine here. Syncing Google calendar with Evolution on Ubuntu 11.04. + all events (whether created with Google Calendar or Evolution Calendar) appear in Unity panel date/time applet

Comment: The best way is to use [syncevolution](https://syncevolution.org/). It sync evolution data with google calendar using caldav.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Calendar Extension for Thunderbird**

Install this plug-in: [xul-ext-lightning](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xul-ext-lightning) [image: Install xul-ext-lightning]

---

**Google calendar and Evolution....**

Currently there is a bug in evolution. A workaround to do the following:

- [Option to sync to Google Calendar doesn't show up in Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73828/option-to-sync-to-google-calendar-doesnt-show-up-in-evolution/73856#73856)

---

**How to migrate from evolution to Thunderbird...**

- [Migrating from Evolution to Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird/27413#27413)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Thunderbird with the addon Lightning to integrate my GCal with Ubuntu and I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Calender indicator.
It's integrated in the top bar of ubuntu and it just shows as a small calender indicator with the date in it. If you click it you can see your google calender which you add on first startup of the program.

I would suggest to try it, it is very small and very handy.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install calender-indicator
```

Next just run it from the Dash. Enjoy!