# How do I move all my data from Evolution to Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating from Evolution to Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird)

I have searched Google and can not find an easy solution to move all mail and calendar information from evolution to the now default Thunderbird. I have added Lightening as an add-on to Thunderbird.

Is there such a tool for Mail, address books and calendars??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an automated tool to accomplish this.

A fairly straightforward walk-through:
http://nucleussystems.com/blog/migrate-evolution-to-thunderbird

You can ask about any specific difficulty.