# How to move calanders from Evolution to Lightning

Tags: evolution, thunderbird, calendar, lightning

How do I move/copy calendars from Evolution to Lightning?

Answer (score 3):

In Evolution, save the calendar as an .ics file as follows:

1. In **Calendars**, right click on the calendar you wish to transfer and select **Save As**
2. Save the calendar as a file of the **iCalendar (.ics)** file type

In Thunderbird, import the file you just saved as follows:

1. Go to the **Events and Tasks** menu and click on **Import...**
2. Select the **iCalendar (*.ics)** file type in the import dialog and import the file saved from Evolution

Answer (score 0):

---

**How to migrate from evolution to thunderbird...**

- [Migrating from Evolution to Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird/27413#27413)