# moving files between evolution and thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating from Evolution to Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird)

I can't find an up to date explanation on how to move all files from evolution to Thunderbird.

IE: mail, address books and calendars to lightning.

With up to date on file locations.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance. Bob.