# How to migrate from Evolution with Maildir to Thunderbird

Tags: 11.10, evolution, thunderbird, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating from Evolution to Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird)

After Upgrading to 11.10 Evolution convert at first start the my Mails into the Maildir format.

Now I want to change my Mail Program to Thunderbird. Is there any Migration Guide (maybe a official one; since this Migration many User are doing, since the default changed) or similar for this. I found only Instruction for the old mbox format.

Answer (score 1):

Why not install IMAP locally and put the mails there.
After that you should be able to connect thunderbird and sync it with the IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a solution for this on Ubuntu Forums:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870445