# Where is Thunderbird's Tools Menu?

Tags: thunderbird, appmenu

I just successfully upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04, and these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird) appear to be exactly what I want. However, for the life of me, I cannot find Thunderbird's tools menu to import my Evolution email.

I am using Thunderbird installed as part of the 12.04 upgrade, and the Thunderbird global menu package is installed. I checked. I cannot find how to indicate what version Thunderbird is other than it was installed as part of 12.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally to get the menu items, we need to install global menu

`sudo apt-get install thunderbird-globalmenu`

Since you have already installed this, I think the problem should be with your thunderbird.

To fix this issue can you try removing the Thunderbird version that is currently installed. and add the ppa provided by mozilla team using

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`

and install Thunderbird new version (v15 I guess).

If the above works then you should be able to access the tools from global menu

Comment: After issuing your two commands, Thunderbird was re-installed. I did not have to do anything else.

Comment: After all this, I cannot find the tools menu. On what do I click?

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is that the menu bar got disabled.
Right-click on the free space next to the "Inbox" tab and select "Menu Bar" if there is no check symbol.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YaVuPxA

Answer (score 0):

Tools was there all along. With this version of Ubuntu (12.04) I did not realize that Unity-behaving applications appear to use a common menu at the top of the screen. Problem solved.