# Switch from Fedora to Ubuntu and Evolution to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, evolution

Presently I have the system with Fedora 15 and Evolution 3.0.3 for emails.
I'm planning to switch my OS to Ubuntu and and Thunderbird for emails.
Is there any way I can do this keeping all my earlier email data imported into Thunderbird with new OS?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird for importing evolution->Tbird from within Ubuntu. Fedora is off topic on AU but I expect you can use the same method on Fedora. Why is this tagged ubuntu-one?!